# All under MySQL_Error() are disappear

Tags: php

I have a problem with disappearing my mysql_error and 50% of my website under error...

```
MySQL_Query("UPDATE table
             SET use = '1'
             WHERE name = '$code'", $SpojenieWeb) or die(mysql_error());
```

Why it is disaappearing ? Where is the error ?

Comment: What is the value of $SpojenieWeb? What are values of `name` in database?

Comment: `use` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you need to quote it in backtics like: `\`use\``. That said i dont think this would cause `MySQL server has gone away.` if that is the error youre talking about.

Answer (score 1):

> *Why it is disaappearing?*

It's disappearing because most probably your UPDATE query fails and you use `die()` in case of failure.

Now it's really hard to say exactly since you provided not enough information, but looking at you query you at least have to change

```
"UPDATE table SET use = '1' WHERE name = '$code' ..."
```

to

```
"UPDATE `table` SET `use` = '1' WHERE name = '$code' ..."
        ^     ^     ^   ^
```

`table` and `use` are [reserved words in Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)